# Can i access Child records while writing a data base trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am writing a DB trigger to update a new table, there are two tables, **TableB** has a Foreign key reference to **TableA**.

My trigger is like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER SCHEMA.TRG_TABLEA 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON **TableA** 
FOR EACH ROW DECLARE 
**data** VARCHAR(1000 CHAR) 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM TableB INTO data WHERE TableA.Id = TableB.Id 
INSERT INTO NewTable (NAME, DATA) 
VALUES (:NEW.NAME, **data**)
END;
```

But the **data** column in newTable is always null, i'm using hibernate in spring boot to insert data in TableA and TableB

any workAround?

Thanks....

Comment: What the column you want to retrieve from `TableB`? Imagine yourself a DBMS and tell what will you put into variable `data` with `select *`.

Comment: There are syntax errors in the code you posted (you can't reference `TableA.id` in the `select`, your `into` is in the wrong position, you can't do a `select *` into a single scalar unless `TableB` happens to have only one column, you're missing semicolons after your `select` and `insert`, etc.  If your actual trigger compiles, which you imply it does because there are rows being inserted into `NewTable`, it's hard for us to guess what the problem might be because we're not looking at code that actually reproduces the problem.